# Bootstrap menu bar using Google Translate CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a css issue as the width of the screen gets smaller will someone please tell me how to adjust my menu bar. I am using the google translate in my menu bar but the problem I am having is when the screen is full size and as you start moving the screen in to make it smaller the google translate starts to drop down to another level making all other dropdowns on the menu bar not work properly because google translate interferes.

Is there a way to make google translate button stay inline or on the menu bar without dropping to another row?

Or even making the width of the google translate not as wide to see if it will stay on the same line?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/bobrierton/5c1vbo2s/11/

```css
.goog-te-gadget .goog-te-combo {
    margin: 0px 0px;
}
.goog-logo-link {
  display:none !important;
} 
.goog-te-gadget{
  color: transparent !important;
  font-size:0px;
}

.goog-te-combo { 
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  color: #687074;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--=== Header v4 ===-->    
    <div class="header-v4">
    
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-default mega-menu" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                                <img id="logo-header" src="assets/img/logo-header.png" alt="Logo">
                                <img id="logo-header" src="assets/img/logo-text.png" alt="Logo text">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 header-right">
       <div class="social margin-bottom-10">
        <ul class="header-links list-inline">
         <li><a href="#" data-original-title="" class="">Apple Store</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-original-title="" class="">Google Play</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="social-icons social-icons-color">
         <li><a href="#" data-original-title="Facebook" class="rounded-x social_facebook"></a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-original-title="Twitter" class="rounded-x social_twitter"></a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-original-title="Youtube" class="rounded-x social_youtube"></a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
                            <button class="btn-u btn-u-lg" type="button"><i class="fa fa-cc-mastercard"></i> Pay Online</button>
       <button class="btn-u btn-u-red btn-u-lg" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Make An Appointment</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                        <span class="full-width-menu">Menu Bar</span>
                        <span class="icon-toggle">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </span>    
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>    

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <div class="container">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <!-- Home -->
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="index.html" class="" data-toggle="">
                                Home
                            </a>

                        </li>
                        <!-- End Home -->

                        <!-- Driver License -->                        
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Driver License
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class=""><a href="sidebar-page.html">General Information</a></li>
                                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Online Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Fees</a></li>
                                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Forms</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Pages -->

                        <!-- Motor Vehicles -->
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Motor Vehicle
                            </a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class=""><a href="sidebar-page.html">General Information</a></li>
                                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Online Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Sales Tax</a></li>
                                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Fees</a></li>
                                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Forms</a></li>
                                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Title By Mail</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>                    
                        <!-- End  -->

                        <!-- Features -->
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Property Tax
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class=""><a href="sidebar-page.html">General Information</a></li>
                                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Lookup/Pay Online</a></li>
                                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Tax Certificates</a></li>
                                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Discount Periods</a></li>
                                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Instalment Options</a></li>
                                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Forms</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Features -->

                        <!-- TDT -->
                       <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Tourist Tax
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class=""><a href="sidebar-page.html">General Information</a></li>
                                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Pay Online</a></li>
                                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Online Account Management</a></li>
                                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Collection Reports</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- Ens  -->

                        <!-- Additional Services -->
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="full-width-page.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Additional Services
                            </a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class=""><a href="sidebar-page.html">Parking Permits</a></li>
                                <li><a href="full-width-page.html">Hunting &amp; Fishing</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- End  -->

                        <!-- Contacts -->
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="contact.html" class="">
                                Contact Us
                            </a>
                           
                        </li>                    
                        <!-- End Contacts -->
                    </ul>

                     <!-- Nav Bar Right Block -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-border-bottom navbar-right"> 
                    <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
                           

<script type="text/javascript">
   function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout}, 'google_translate_element');
   }
  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>  
                    </ul>
                    <!-- End Nav Bar Right Block -->
                </div><!--/end container-->
            </div><!--/navbar-collapse-->
        </div>            
        <!-- End Navbar -->
    </div>
    <!--=== End Header v4 ===-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `white-space: nowrap` BUT you will need to make sure that it fits in the different break points because, as you requested, it will no longer wrap to fit.

```
.header-links {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

After adding this, simply use your media queries to make adjustments through your different breakpoints to get the look/style you desire. An example of using a media query that makes style adjustments UNDER 860px screen width would be:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 859px) {
    .header-links li {
        padding-right: 2px;
        padding-left: 2px;
    }
    .header-links a {
        font-size: 13px;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to eliminate the extra white space in the google select? Say when you select Spanish instead of having all that extra white space can I some how cut a lot of it off? Maybe the it will fit?

Comment: Well, you will need to adjust the css (font-size, margin, etc.) as needed using media queries. Don't be afraid to use a media query specifically targeting a problem point if needed.

Comment: is it possible to do that cutting of the white space? that would probably solve it

Comment: You could try to reduce the padding (and possibly font-size) with a media query. What screen width are you exactly referring to?

Comment: Your display diagonal is: 17.1"
Display dimensions (width x height): 13.3 x 10.7

Comment: Dimensions
Browser window width: 1179
Browser window height: 859
Screen width: 1280
Screen height: 1024
Screen color depth: 24

Comment: I can create a media query for you to use BUT I need the width in pixels, not inches. So you know, sizes as related to web dev are always referred to in pixels or percentages (ie. em, rem,% or an int).

Comment: Ok, I added to my answer that gives you an example of styles adjustments at 859px or less widths. Adjust as needed.